# Control Go package version

Tags: git, go, version-control, go-modules

I am looking for a way to control a go package version on github, something similar to the "version" key in a package.json file (for nodejs packages).

*In a package.json*

```
{
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

I want to import my package in another one, both use go modules. In my second package, my go.mod file looks like this :

```golang
module myPackage

go 1.14

require(
  github.com/myAwesomePackage v0.0.0-20200531102207-93175fe4ed5f
)
```

Now I'd like to make changes to myAwesomePackage, so I can rewrite myPackage mod file like this :

```golang
module myPackage

go 1.14

require(
  github.com/myAwesomePackage v1.1.0
)
```

I tried `git tag 1.1.0` and `git tag v1.1.0` in myAwesomePackage, but 
myPackage gives the following error when trying to update :

```
invalid version: unknown revision v1.1.0
```

**UPDATE**

`git tag` actually worked, the issue seemed to come from my Ide (GoLand). Just rewriting version in go.mod file didn't worked, I had to remove the
entire line in require statement, then let IntelliJ sync again the 
dependencies. Now myAwesomePackage is imported with the correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear whether you're *publishing* a Go module, or whether you're depending on one. Either way, it's simple enough; if you're [publishing](https://blog.golang.org/publishing-go-modules) one, you can just tag a version using `git tag`. If you're [depending](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) on one and would like to lock to a specific version, you can simply modify your project's `go.mod` file and choose a version.

Comment: I'll update my question. I actually want to publish one on github, so in another go.mod file I can import my first package using a controlled version.

Comment: I tried `git tag v1.1.0` on the first package, but when I tried to import it in another go.mod file I got an error `unknown revision v1.1.0`.